# Is it possible to convert a permission value to a permission name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a user info command that has the field and displays user permissions, but it gives me just a permission value.
My code:

```
@client.command()
async def userinfo(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=member.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, title=f'{member.name}#{member.discriminator}')

    ***
   some embed fields
    ***

    embed.add_field(name='Permissions:', value=member.guild_permissions, inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

It gives me `<Permissions value=2146959359>`, so can I convert a value to a permission name? If `member.guild_permissions` is not suitable, what should I use?

Comment: Are you just trying to list all of their permissions as a string? Is that what you mean? e.g. Ban, Kick, Administrator etc.

Comment: @Roope That's the documentation for Discord's API, not discord.py.

Comment: @Kelo yea, that's correct.

Comment: @Roope How discord.py represents the permissions is not in the documentation for Discord's API.

Comment: @Harmon758 yet my point still stands, reading the documentation should easily solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`Permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions) object represents all available permissions. That's why the [`value`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.value) is a 53-bit integer.
You can iterate over the `Permissions` object for `(name, value)` pairs, but note, that uses the attribute names. Alternatively, you could just map the attribute names to permission names yourself and use the attributes to get the values.